# This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded

Tags: c#

I'm getting this error when trying to start a **.net 4**  **windows service**.
I tried a few things I found when I googled the problem:

I checked that all projects that being referred from my project have, in their
  app.config, the lines:

```
<startup>
 <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

- I verified that I have .Net 4 Framework installed on my **server 2008R2 machine**.
- I did the repair of .Net 4 installer and restarted the server.
- I set the Startup object to my service.

All projects complied with x64.

I'm out of ideas... help anybody?

Comment: What assembly being referenced is throwing the error? - Is it .Net 4.5?

Comment: I'm almost sure that not all your projects are targeting the .NET Framework 4 and more precisely: The entry point of the entire app (the main executable project) is targeting 3.0, 3.5 or anything less that 4 or 4.5. Please check that and tell us if that is true...

Comment: Your application pool is set to handle .NET 4?

Comment: Also, the app.config files of class libraries being referenced by your main executable can very well not exist (in this case). They don't change things. It's the app.config of the entry executable that counts. Furthemore: The question is **not what what the app.config** of the actual entry contains but rather what version of the .NET does the actual entry executable target...

Comment: I double checked that :( all the project referenced (at least those that I have access to) are targeted .Net 4 (Not 4.5 it is compiled on VS 2010)

Comment: @betelgeuce I think he's not running the **service** it in IIS. It's just a Windows service. choppy: Are trying to host a **WEB service** in IIS ?

Comment: @ Eduard Dumitru is right it is a windows service

Comment: When you say "referenced projects" are you also including the main executable (that isn't referenced by anyone..., the one which produces and .EXE assembly, not a .DLL assembly ?) Is that 4.0 also ? Furthemore: 4.5 would be fine. A 4.0 CLR can successfully load 4.5 assemblies (no problem there). But a 3.5 or 3.0 CLR cannot ever load a 4.0 or 4.5 assembly. The CLR version is determined by the Main executable's (entry assembly) .NET version.

Comment: @betelgeuce :) you're right: it's a windows service (no app pools) :)

Comment: @Rob Hardy: you actually **can** load a 4.5 assembly in a 4.0 CLR (it's just that Visual Studio won't allow you to reference it "syntactically")

Comment: Can you check that you have the .net 4 extended profile installed. Also might be worth installing all the sp.

Comment: I have:
 1. Microsoft .NET CompactFramework 2.0 SP2..................                         
 2. Microsoft .NET CompactFramework 3.5 ..................                         
 3. Microsoft .NET CompactFramework 4 Client Profile................
 4. Microsoft .NET CompactFramework 4 Extended..................
 Microsoft .NET CompactFramework 4 Multi-Trargeting Pack

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is the "Target Framework" setting on the "Application" tab of your project properties.

Make sure all of them are compatible, e.g. all of them are set to ".NET Framework 4".